# gform_pre_render Dropdown populated with roles

Tags: plugin-gravity-forms, user-roles

I'm using gravity forms and trying to prepopulate a dropdown with a list of roles.  This is what I have, but it's coming up with an error:

```
add_filter("gform_pre_render", "gform_prepopluate_populate_role");

//Note: when changing drop down values, we also need to use the gform_admin_pre_render so that the right values are displayed when editing the entry.
add_filter("gform_admin_pre_render", "gform_prepopluate_populate_role");

function gform_prepopluate_populate_role($form){
    global $wp_roles;
    $posttype = 'em_companies';
    $formid = '5';
    $fieldid = '8';

    //only populating drop down for form id 5
    if($form["id"] != $formid)
       return $form;

    //Reading posts for "Business" category;
    //$posts = query_posts(array('post_type' => array('post', 'movies')));
   $roles = query_posts( array( $wp_roles->get_names() ) );
   // if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

    //Creating drop down item array.
    $items = array();

    //Adding initial blank value.
    $items[] = array("text" => "", "value" => "");

    //Adding post titles to the items array
    foreach($roles as $role)
        $items[] = array("value" => $role, "text" => $role );

    //Adding items to field id 8. Replace 8 with your actual field id. You can get the field id by looking at the input name in the markup.
    foreach($form["fields"] as &$field)
        if($field["id"] == $fieldid ){            
            $field["choices"] = $items;
        }

    return $form;
}
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're nearly there...

The 'query_posts' function is only intended to return posts (and other post types) so this will not work for roles. The line `$roles = ...` is likely the cause of your error

instead it should just be:

`$roles = $wp_roles->get_names();`